# AngularJS and Chart JS - Expression not executing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I have a very basic piece of code with a canvas (Chart.js) and some information. My problem is that angularjs is showing the expression instead of executing the code.

I already tried to use `ng-bind` and `$scope.$apply()` but it didn't work.

If I put the label in any other place of the page, it executes as expected. If it was inside the canvas I may understand but it's outside...

[image]

```js
(function() {
  'use strict';

  angular.module('GHoF').controller('CreatorDashboardCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', 'apiBaseURL', function($scope, $http, apiBaseURL) {


    $scope.getCreatorStats = () => {
      $http.get(`${apiBaseURL}/creator/stats?username=${localStorage.getItem('username')}`).then(res => {
          $scope.creatorStats = res.data;
          console.log($scope.creatorStats);
        },
        (err) => {
          console.error(err);
        });
    }
    $scope.getCreatorStats();

    var ctx3 = $('.colors-pie-chart'),
      data3 = {
        type: 'doughnut',
        data: {
          datasets: [{
            data: [37, 47, 16],
            borderWidth: [0, 0, 0],
            backgroundColor: [
              "#7c5ac2",
              "#03f1b6",
              "#108fe9"
            ],
            hoverBackgroundColor: [
              "#7c5ac2",
              "#03f1b6",
              "#108fe9"
            ]
          }]
        },
        options: {
          legend: {
            display: false
          },
          tooltips: {
            enabled: false
          },
          cutoutPercentage: 75
        }
      },
      colorsPieChart = new Chart(ctx3, data3);

  }]);
})();
```

```html
<div class="colors-pie-chart-wrap">
  <canvas class="colors-pie-chart"></canvas>
  <div class="chart-description">
    <p class="text-header">{{creatorStats.points}}</p>
    <p class="text-header">Points</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

ANy idea?

Comment: Do you have any error in your Javascript console ?

Comment: check the console for errors if there paste it in the question

Comment: angular.js:15570 TypeError: Cannot read property 'childNodes' of undefined
    at compositeLinkFn (angular.js:9838)
    at compositeLinkFn (angular.js:9838)
    at compositeLinkFn (angular.js:9838)
    at compositeLinkFn (angular.js:9838)
    at compositeLinkFn (angular.js:9838)
    at publicLinkFn (angular.js:9700)
    at Object.link (angular-route.js:1260)
    at angular.js:1390
    at invokeLinkFn (angular.js:11269)
    at nodeLinkFn (angular.js:10588) "<main ng-view="" class="ng-scope">"

Comment: but it works in other labels. Only doesnt work for this